# Xamarin IOS LaunchScreen.Storyboard cant select image for Image view

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using (Windows)Visual Studio 2017 
[I follow this instruction step by step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=vswin)

 1 - Add Asset and upload all images needed 
2 - Create `LaunchScreen.storyboard` 
3 - Set `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in `Info.plist` 
*** The Problem in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` when I add `Image View` and select Image**

[image]

When i Click on down arrow to select image from assets it automatically open upload dialog and when I select image nothing happened

[image]

Comment: Did you update your VS ? I updated it today to 15.8.4 and had the same issue.After I delete the folders obj and bin and rebuild the project,it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I got this phenomenon in Xarmain.Forms project like you.
Finally,I slove this by Once you compile(Ctrl+Shift+B) the project, you can add the image.
You can try. Wish you success.
[Operating as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbAy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with VS only, try restarting your VS once.
You can try updating it also.
When I faced this issue I was fortunate to have a mac with me, it works absolutely fine on VS for Mac. 
So if you want a quick resolution you can trying doing only this part on VS for Mac.