# Xamarin Forms (iOS) - Can't select images from Assets.xcassets for ImageView control

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms project where I am trying to add a logo to the LaunchScreen.storyboard.  As you can see in the image below, the Properties pane Image property only shows what is in the Resources folder...

[image]

[image]

My Assets.xcassets has several images defined (labels say 'icon', but these are all images).  The app_logo image is the one I need to choose from the drop down.

[image]

Is this a bug?  Or am I doing something wrong?

I found this [post with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456797/xamarin-ios-launchscreen-storyboard-cant-select-image-for-image-view), but I have restarted Visual Studio, cleaned, Rebuild All, and still having the same problem.

Comment: Which version of Xamarin Forms , it's a strange phenomenon. If have time, you can share a sample project , I will check in local .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by opening the sln in VS 2019 Preview.  Not sure why 2017 wouldn't let me do it.